# What is the Apache BytesLog directive useful for?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, apache-1.3

What does it do? Is it part of a module or part of the core Apache server?

I have a BytesLog setup for a bunch of virtualhosts and they don't seem to do much. All I see are a list of numbers when I open up a bytes log file and I can't see how it would be useful for monitoring Apache performance.

Answer (score 1):

Its useful for determining how much traffic apache has been transferring. This might be useful for accounting how much traffic a given user/customer/domain is responsible for.